# How can I open a desk drawer that is jammed closed by the stuff inside?

Tags: desk, drawers

I have a desk drawer that I need to get into but it only opens and inch. I had a lot of stuff packed inside, I'm not sure if something is jammed.

Comment: Well, you could use a Sawz-All...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open it so it jams then back it off a bit, so whatever is causing the jam is not stuck. Then using a ruler, piece of cardboard, or other flat object, work it into the gap so it rests above the drawer contents and presses down on them (or just guides them) to free them from the drawer or frame above.

Comment: I didn't think the ruler would work so well!

Answer (score 4):

The ruler idea usually works for me. If not ...

If there is a draw below it, pull it out, then you may be able to reach under and up behind the jammed upper drawer and move the contents around or pull some out.

Answer (score 2):

Can you shake it a bit or get a coat hanger (or some other sturdy wire) inside and try to reposition whatever is holding it closed?

Comment: Shaking almost always works for me, especially if the drawer is full of lot of little things.

Comment: Shake it how? Side to side, back and forth, up and down? I can't see what is holding it closed.

Comment: Shake it any or all of those ways. You don't have to see what it is holding it closed to be able to shift it around.

Answer (score 1):

I just opened my stuck desk drawer with a long handled spatula - the flat piece worked wonders moving the drawer contents around  - worked better than the butter knife, ruler and wire coat hanger I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by emptying the hutch with the stuck drawer of everything in the lower
cabinet & removing the shelf unit that rested on the hutch. Then I 'man handled' the unit,
left, right, back & forward until the obstruction ( a picture frame!) became loosened. The other solutions were not right for my particular problem. Whew!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by taking a butter knife because it has a very thin metallic part that can move the picture frame that was stuck